# Intel PIN tool: Get a trace of EFLAGS values

Tags: x86, intel, instrumentation, intel-pin

I am trying to get a complete dynamic trace of a program using Intel PIN tool. My trace would have : {Instruction address, Instruction, Operands, EFLAGS, OPCODES}.

I have managed to get the first three using xed-interface.H provided in the kit. Now, I want to get the EFLAGS state at each instruction. Also, I would like to get the opcodes in the same file.

Which API should I use to achieve this?

Comment: Okay I found something in the manual: In the LEVEL_CORE Namespace  reference page, there's an enumeration type LEVEL_CORE::FLAGS mentioned. Though I didn't get how to use it in my pintool.

Answer (score 0):

Add IARG_CONST_CONTEXT  to the list of arguments in the INS_InsertCall() call in the instrumentation routine.
Then you can call PIN_GetContextRegval(ctx, REG_EFLAGS, &pin_register) to get the value of eflags in pin_register.

Comment: If this is killing your performance take a look at partial context which can be used to get the same effect.